# I can't seem to return my hash value associated with the group of words at each table[ ] mem location

Tags: c++, arraylist, hash, linked-list

This was a 2 part problem, implementing a Trie and a Hash->linked lists

the files contain words for a to z in column format... basically searching for words in the input file from an output file.
The trouble we are having is printing the hash value associated at each memory location in out table.
Words are sorted based on their ACII value sum.

abc and bcd will be placed into same bucket/or created hash value.

ignore the commented code as we have been using/saving most of everything we type and find in out textbook.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int N = 111;

//int HashNode *table[N];

//======================================//
//           CLASS DEFINITIONS          //
//======================================//


// Node class
class Node {

public:
    Node(string lab) { mContent = lab[0]; mMarker = false; mLabel = lab; }
    ~Node() {}

    string mLabel;
    char mContent;
    bool mMarker;
    vector<Node*> mChildren;    
    Node *rightsibling;
    Node *firstchild;

    char content() { return mContent; }
    void setContent(char c) { mContent = c; }
    bool wordMarker() { return mMarker; }
    void setWordMarker() { mMarker = true; }
    vector<Node*> children() { return mChildren; }
    Node* findChild(char c);
    void appendChild(Node* child) { mChildren.push_back(child); }
};


// Trie class
class Trie {

private:
    Node* root;    

public:
    Trie();
    ~Trie();
    void insert(string s);
    bool search(string s);
    bool search2(string s);
};


// Hash class
class HashNode{

private:
    int tableSize;
    Node *parent;   //pointer to parent node
    char c;         //next character of word being hashed
    Node *child;    //pointer to child node
    HashNode *next;     //pointer to next node in LL Hash
    HashNode(Node *p,char c,Node *q);

public:
    HashNode();
    void HashInsert(Node *p, char c, Node *q);
    int calc_hash(Node *p, char c);
    void preorder( Node *p);
    Node *findChild2(Node *parent, char c);
};

HashNode *table[N]; //global hashtable array


//======================================//
//          METHOD DEFINITIONS          //
//======================================//


// FindChild Method
Node* Node::findChild(char c)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < mChildren.size(); i++ )
    {
        Node* tmp = mChildren.at(i);
        if ( tmp->content() == c )
        {
            return tmp;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}


// Trie Constructor
Trie::Trie()
{
    root = new Node(" ");
}


// Trie Destructor
Trie::~Trie()
{
    // Free memory
}


// Insert Method
void Trie::insert(string s)
{
    Node* current = root;

    if ( s.length() == 0 )
    {
        current->setWordMarker(); // an empty word
        return;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ )
    {        
        Node* child = current->findChild(s[i]);
        if ( child != NULL )
        {
            current = child;
            int j=0;
            string s1, s2, s3;
            Node *p, *q;
            while((j < current->mLabel.length()) && (current->mLabel[j] == s[i])){j++;i++;}
            if ((j<current->mLabel.length())) {
                //split current
                s1=current->mLabel.substr(0,j-1);
                s2=current->mLabel.substr(j,current->mLabel.length()-1);
                s3=s.substr(i,s.length()-1); //if i = s.length then ...s3 should be empty string
                p=new Node(s3);
                p->setWordMarker();
                q=new Node(s2);
                q->firstchild = current->firstchild;
                current->mLabel = s1;
                if(s3 < s2){
                    p->rightsibling=q;
                    q->rightsibling = NULL;
                    current->firstchild = p;
                }
                else {
                    q->rightsibling=p;
                    p->rightsibling = NULL;
                    current->firstchild = q;
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Node* tmp = new Node(" ");
            tmp->setContent(s[i]);
            current->appendChild(tmp);
            current = tmp;
        }
        if ( i == s.length() - 1 )
            current->setWordMarker();
    }
}


// Search Method1
bool Trie::search(string s)
{
    Node* current = root;

    while ( current != NULL )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ )
        {
            Node* tmp = current->findChild(s[i]);
            if ( tmp == NULL )
                return false;
            current = tmp;
        }

        if ( current->wordMarker() )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    return false;
}


// SEARCH METHOD 2
bool Trie::search2(string s)
{
    Node* current = root;

    while ( current != NULL )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ )
        {
            Node* tmp = current->findChild(s[i]);
            if ( tmp == NULL )
                return false;
            current = tmp;
        }

        if ( current->wordMarker() )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    return false;
}


// Hash Constructor
HashNode::HashNode(Node *p,char c,Node *q){
    tableSize = N;
    parent =p;
    c = c;
    child = q;
}

int HashNode::calc_hash(Node *p, char c){
    int a = N/3;
    int i = *((int*)(&p)); //int i = (int)p;
    int j = (int)c;
    int h = (a*i + j) % N;
    return h;

}

void HashNode::HashInsert(Node *p, char c, Node *q){
    int h = calc_hash(p,c);
    HashNode *x = table[h];
    HashNode *y = new HashNode(p,c,q);

    if (x==NULL)
        table[h]=y;
    while (x->next != NULL)
        x = x->next;
    x->next = y;

    //y->next = x;
    //table[h] = y;
}


void HashNode::preorder( Node *p) {
    if (p==NULL) return;
    Node *q = p->firstchild;
    while (q != NULL){
        HashInsert(p,q->mContent, q);
        preorder(q);
        q = q->rightsibling;
    }
}


Node *HashNode::findChild2(Node *parent, char c){
    int h = calc_hash(parent, c);
    HashNode *p = table[h];
    while (p != NULL){
        if (p->parent == parent && p->c == c){
            return p->child;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
}

//======================================//
//                 MAIN                 //
//======================================//

int main()
{
    Trie* trie = new Trie();
    HashNode hashObj;
    //HashEntryNode Hashtable[N];

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("testdata.txt");
    if (!infile)
        cout<<"Input file cannot be openned!"<<endl;
    cout<<"---------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"List of words inserted into Trie:"<<endl;
    cout<<"---------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    string wordLine;
    while (!infile.eof()){
        infile >> wordLine;
        trie->insert(wordLine);
        cout<<wordLine<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"---------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"           End of List           "<<endl;
    cout<<"---------------------------------"<<endl<<endl;

    ifstream searchFile;
    searchFile.open("searchdata.txt");
    if(!searchFile)
        cout<<"Search file cannot be openned!"<<endl;

    string searchLine;
    while (!searchFile.eof()){
        searchFile >> searchLine;
        if ( trie->search(searchLine) )
            cout << searchLine <<" => FOUND!" << endl;
        else 
            cout << searchLine <<" => NOT FOUND." <<endl;


        int h;
        char p;
       // h = hashObj.calc_hash(searchLine);
        cout << "hash value is "<< h << endl;


        //int index;
        //index = hashObj.hashFunction(searchLine);
        //cout << "Hash value = " << index <<endl<<endl;
        //Hashtable[index] = 
    }


    delete trie;
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your main() routine doesn't call any of your hash functions. Also, I would have expected your hash function to be a function of a string, not a function of the pointer to a node. Maybe that's what you want, but if you are hashing strings you usually hash the string.

Comment: we had the has function of a string, but our professor did it like this on the board today in class....Can you give me an example of how to call the hashNode functions from the main? where does the input parameter node *p come from in our hashNode functions?

Comment: No, I don't have your assignment in front of me and it's not obvious from the code what your prof intends for you to do.

Comment: Why did you tag this question C?